# Learn a music instrument

Tags: sharia, music

Being a Muslim is it correct to learn guitar. As I've always been attracted towards it but i dnt want to do anything which makes Allah angry. So is it correct???? But there is a saying that our prophet mohammad (PBUH) came here to bann all the Music instruments.

Answer (score 1):

The Quran does not prohibit musical instruments in any explicit or non-explicit sense.

The issue is disputed through secondary sources as per alleged sayings of Rasulullah.

Muslims throughout the ages have differed on the issue of instruments because of the multiplicity of narrations reaching us and their authenticity not being 100% established.

Those who considered them to be authentic have used them to prohibit instruments.

Those who considered the narrations to be unreliable have said that instruments are permissible, and they also argued from Quran saying it does not prohibit them.

One famous hadith that is repeated for the case of prohibition was mentioned in 'Sahih al-Bukhari' under the Book of Drinks:

وَقَالَ هِشَامُ بْنُ عَمَّارٍ حَدَّثَنَا صَدَقَةُ بْنُ خَالِدٍ، حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنُ يَزِيدَ بْنِ جَابِرٍ، حَدَّثَنَا عَطِيَّةُ بْنُ قَيْسٍ الْكِلاَبِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنُ غَنْمٍ الأَشْعَرِيُّ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنِي أَبُو عَامِرٍ ـ أَوْ أَبُو مَالِكٍ ـ الأَشْعَرِيُّ وَاللَّهِ مَا كَذَبَنِي سَمِعَ النَّبِيَّ  يَقُولُ

‏ "‏ لَيَكُونَنَّ مِنْ أُمَّتِي أَقْوَامٌ يَسْتَحِلُّونَ الْحِرَ وَالْحَرِيرَ وَالْخَمْرَ وَالْمَعَازِفَ، وَلَيَنْزِلَنَّ أَقْوَامٌ إِلَى جَنْبِ عَلَمٍ يَرُوحُ عَلَيْهِمْ بِسَارِحَةٍ لَهُمْ، يَأْتِيهِمْ ـ يَعْنِي الْفَقِيرَ ـ لِحَاجَةٍ فَيَقُولُوا ارْجِعْ إِلَيْنَا غَدًا‏.‏ فَيُبَيِّتُهُمُ اللَّهُ وَيَضَعُ الْعَلَمَ، وَيَمْسَخُ آخَرِينَ قِرَدَةً وَخَنَازِيرَ إِلَى يَوْمِ الْقِيَامَةِ ‏"

"From among my followers there will be some people who will consider illegal sexual intercourse, the wearing of silk, the drinking of alcoholic drinks and the use of musical instruments, as lawful. And there will be some people who will stay near the side of a mountain and in the evening their shepherd will come to them with their sheep and ask them for something, but they will say to him, 'Return to us tomorrow.' Allah will destroy them during the night and will let the mountain fall on them, and He will transform the rest of them into monkeys and pigs and they will remain so till the Day of Resurrection."

That is their proof.  Those who oppose this Hadith, counter it as following (summary):

First, you should notice that al-Bukhari himself did not give the full chain of narration for this hadith and mentions it by saying "wa qaala"; leaving out the person who reported it and leaving it suspended (muallaq).  This indicates that he did not consider it as an authentic hadith.

Second, he put it under the Book of Drinks and not proof for prohibition of musical instruments.

Third, there are three problematic people in the isnad that are adding on to the unreliability of this hadith:

Hishaam b. 'Ammaar (sadok/da'ef), 'Abdur Rahman b. Yazid b. Jaabir (matruk al-hadith/da'ef), and 'Atiyah b. Qays (sadok/hasan).  None of these men were considered as 100% upright and reliable (thiqa/thabt).  They all had issues in their transmissions.

It is up to you to conclude with a clear mind.

Comment: I would recommend a book on this issue... which takes into account all of these matters of ZUUF in ahadees on this and etc...
named الغنا والمعازف you can get a copy from here http://www.alukah.net/books/files/book_3377/bookfile/alghenaa.pdf

Answer (score -1):

**Yes, Music is haraam.**

I know it is quite difficult to sacrifice hobby. But, Allah knows best, What is best for us. If we sacrifice something for Allah, In sha Allah, Allah grant us higher rank for our sacrifice.

"Ya Allah give us happiness. Aameeen"

**From Quraan and Sunnah we can understand prohibition of music.**

[For more details follow Fatwa on Music on https://IslamQA.info/en/5000](https://islamqa.info/en/5000)

**One reference from Quraan:**

Allaah says in Soorat Luqmaan (interpretation of the meaning):

> “And of mankind is he who purchases idle talks (i.e. music, singing) to mislead (men) from the path of Allaah…” [Luqmaan 31:6]

The scholar of the ummah, Ibn ‘Abbaas (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: this means singing. Mujaahid (may Allaah have mercy on him) said: this means playing the drum (tabl). (Tafseer al-Tabari, 21/40).

Al-Hasan al-Basri (may Allaah have mercy on him) said: this aayah was revealed concerning singing and musical instruments (lit. woodwind instruments). (Tafseer Ibn Katheer, 3/451).

Al-Sa’di (may Allaah have mercy on him) said: this includes all manner of haraam speech, all idle talk and falsehood, and all nonsense that encourages kufr and disobedience; the words of those who say things to refute the truth and argue in support of falsehood to defeat the truth; and backbiting, slander, lies, insults and curses; the singing and musical instruments of the Shaytaan; and musical instruments which are of no spiritual or worldly benefit. (Tafseer al-Sa’di, 6/150)

**One reference from hadith:**

> It was narrated that Naafi’ (may Allaah have mercy on him) said: Ibn ‘Umar heard a woodwind instrument, and he put his fingers in his ears and kept away from that path. He said to me, O Naafi’, can you hear anything? I said, No. So he took his fingers away from his ears and said: I was with the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) and he heard something like this, and he did the same thing. (Saheeh Abi Dawood)

Comment: The ayah says lahw al-hadith, which means amusing speech, or tales. Instruments don't tell tales. This is in reference to those who try to mislead others from Allah's way by using such means and in no way prohibits musical instruments.

Comment: @DeathlessLight 
I don't know how your translation is different from scholars of Ummah....
check this fatwa for more details https://islamqa.info/en/5000

Comment: I don’t understand how come listening to music is forbidden. Or singing a song is forbidden. Then how come some they have a great talent on singing on a specific song? Is that a test from God? Or, if the song contains bad message then it is forbidden and if it contains good message then it is good? Or both of them are forbidden?

Comment: All songs are not forbidden, but all musical instruments are forbidden except from duff. (There are scholarly different opinion on use of duff as musical instrument.) Song without music with halal lyrics and halal intention is not prohibited. @alex-a 

Allah knows best.. May Allah guide us..

Check these fatwas for more details https://islamqa.info/en/cat/2008

Comment: @MuhammadibnAbdullah I see. So that’s why when a guy went to the house of prophet Muhammad and he said to the girls “musical instruments in the house of the Holy Prophet?” and Muhammad said: “Every nation has its own celebration”.

Comment: yeah! It is about daff::
**Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 944; Muslim, 892**

Open this fatwa to know When is it permissible to beat the daff https://islamqa.info/en/20406