# Is it allowed to sing verses of the Quran in a choral setting?

Tags: music

After reading several answers on this site,

[Is music allowed if it helps you think of God? (Sunni View)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7926/is-music-allowed-if-it-helps-you-think-of-god-sunni-view?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[What is the Islamic definition of music?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7797/what-is-the-islamic-definition-of-music?rq=1)

[If someone is not distracted from Islam by music, is it still haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39100/if-someone-is-not-distracted-from-islam-by-music-is-it-still-haram?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Which prominent Sunni scholars say music is not haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40087/which-prominent-sunni-scholars-say-music-is-not-haram?rq=1)

[Learn a music instrument](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30150/learn-a-music-instrument)

I get the impression that religious music different from the usual recitation of the Qur'an is often not appreciated but opinions differ. In particular, in the first Q&A, there are two views opposing each other; the negative answer not really being supported by authorative sources. I personally do not really see why Qur'an verses should not be set into beautiful music as it arose in the European (Christian) culture from the 12th Century a.D (6th a.H). I would like to split the question into three aspects:

1. Is there any explicit interdiction in Hadith (or in the Holy Qur'an where I have not found it)?
2. Have any scolars explicitly opposed to ornamental or choral music for worship? Who and where?
3. Would I rise anger among Muslim societies if I set verses of the Holy Qur'an in its original into (a-capella) music?

The difference to prior questions is that it is not only about «music with a good intention» but the aspect to worship God the Most High and recite the Holy Qur'an by the means of multi-voice music.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Assalamu 'alaikum dear Brothers and Sisters.**

There are no prohibitions on group melodic (makam) recitation of the Qur'an. Before releasing our project, we conducted extensive research on the permissibility of this method of recitation. Below is a selection of fatwas on this topic.

Video clip https://youtu.be/coM5V9D_f04
Fatwas https://ihsanlab.com/fatwas/

I confess some Arabian qari were outraged by this method. But they did not provide any proof of the correctness of their position. We follow the Hadith "Decorate the Qur'an with your voices". And we did it. Ma sha Allah

Answer (score 0):

Recitation of the Qur'an differs from singing, it said – and singing the Qur'an to a tune is forbidden. According to al-Azhar, adding a tune makes the Qur'an comparable to songs and reduces the capacity of the readers and listeners to understand the true meaning of the verses.

Comment: I found https://www.dar-alifta.org/Foreign/ViewFatwa.aspx?ID=4867 which is positive to singing in general, as well as other fatwas that are negative in general. My question is really about singing the Word of God from the Quran. Could you please cite or link your source? Thank you

Comment: Just look up is it haram to sing the Quran it’s says no so you shouldn’t risk it. Because if you still don’t know that’s the best way to say it, Allah knows best.

Answer (score -1):

Returning to the intentions of our group project, I suggest that you familiarize with the prequel video

https://youtu.be/NTX_sDMQdEk